# How can I link to featured music section in iTunes store application from my iphone application?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

To be more descriptive, I do NOT want to link to particular song, or album as affiliation links. But only want to link to open the iTunes app with featured music section as open. Just like it is linked in iPhone's native music player application.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send the user to the following URL - this will open the music store to the Featured tab.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/store

FWIW - this link works on both the desktop and mobile.